# Salvage my turkey chili? Cinnamon fail!

Tags: turkey, chili, cinnamon, mistakes

Making turkey chili for the week's dinners. Three tablespoons of chili powder: one, two, CRUD THAT"S CINNAMON!

I now have a slow cooker holding 1.5 pounds of turkey meat, cooked onion and two green peppers, and two TABLESPOONS of cinnamon. I have read recipes with cinnamon in chili, but never so much. Can anyone make a recommendation to save this dish?

Other items I have on hand and was expecting to use include chili powder, cocoa powder, other spices, diced tomatoes, stewed tomatoes, several times of canned beans (pinto - black or brown; chickpeas). And a few other things around the house.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Would love to see what others think, but I think I found a solution that works for our palate! Used a tiny bit of cocoa powder, 1/3 the usual chili powder. Just a little black pepper for hot, but we don't like hot generally. I used the usual stewed and diced tomatoes, but eliminated the tomato paste to allow the cinnamon musty to dominate. This also allowed me to skip the honey too. And I used richer flavored beans than I usually do - pintos instead of white kidney beans.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the hotter the dish, the less noticeable the cinnamon.

I would not add cocoa powder, but put in as much chili powder (or even better, fresh or jarred hot peppers) as is palatable to you.